# android: sending email automatically

Tags: android, file, email

at first sorry for my English. I need to make app that will 
automatically send a file from the SD card. I thought that I will do 
it through email. I write the code to send email

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
public class EmailActivity extends Activity { 
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    } 
    public void poslat(View button) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                String Email[] = { "a@aa.aa" }; 
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Email); 
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tu bude datum"); 
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/lala/ 
lala.txt")); 
                i.setType("plain/text"); 
                startActivity(i); 
        } 
}
```

works well, but I feel that it cannot be configured to be sending 
automatically. How can I start? or do you have any idea how to 
automatically send a file from the SD card? eg. via FTP or something 
else? .. Thank you very much

---

i have got this code

Mail.java

```
package mail.mail;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 
  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 
  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 
  private String _host; 
  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 
  private boolean _auth; 
  private boolean _debuggable; 
  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 
    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  public String getSubject() { 
        return _subject; 
      } 

  public void setSubject(String _subject) { 
        this._subject = _subject; 
      } 

  public String getFrom() { 
        return _from; 
      } 
  public void setFrom(String _from) { 
        this._from = _from; 
      } 
  public String[] getTO() { 
        return _to; 
      } 
  public void setTo(String[] _to) { 
        this._to = _to; 
      } 
  // more of the getters and setters ….. 


}
```

lala.java

```
package mail.mail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class lala extends Activity{
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
      super.onCreate(icicle); 
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 

      Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
      addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view) { 
          Mail m = new Mail("aa@gmail.com", "aa"); 

          String[] toArr = {"aaa@centrum.sk"}; 
          m.setTo(toArr); 
          m.setFrom("aa@gmail.com"); 
          m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
          m.setBody("Email body.");

          try { 
            m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 



          } catch(Exception e) { 
            //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
          } 
        } 
      }); 
    } 

}
```

what is wrong here?.. =//

Answer (score 2):

If you like to send an email without user interaction you can use SMTP protocol and outside mail server

Comment: than can i  will send it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear... do you mean you simply want the app to send the email without requiring the user to press a button?  More likely, I'd guess you're asking about Android's background service functionality, where your app runs on a schedule and sends email without user interaction.  If that's the case, start with the Android documentation:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: EDIT: I want to do app that will record something and save it to txt file, then say every 10 minutes it will send this txt file somewhere to  FTP or Email .. or something .. and I thought of it via email is the easiest. all automatically, user only start app and that's all. It may not be background service. This app can be displayed on phone.

Answer (score -1):

The intent system is a way to switch between `Activities`. Here is the intent you defined:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Email); 
                ...
                i.setType("plain/text");
```

The intent is then used to **start an activity** not send an email

```
            startActivity(i);
```

Instead of using the built in email client which is designed to allow users to create and read emails you simply need to implement the SMTP protocols and you can then send the email in the background without user interaction.  If you search on google you will find many examples of how to do this. Here are two that are very informative:

- http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android
- [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)

Comment: i try both of this but no one work for me.. i dont know what im doing wrong. in eclipse is everithing ok but when im try start it in mobile it crashed

Comment: telling someone "it crashed" does no good, you need to post stack traces and error messages.

Comment: Sorry! The application xy..has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: @user985603, that is not what I meant. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html